# after login dynamic menu API getting CORS error

Tags: php, angular, rest, api, angular6

I am using Angular 6 and codeigniter project.in the project I am using slider and nav menu-bar are dynamically fetching through REST API. Normally its working perfectly after Login its occurring the CORS error

[image]

after login its getting like this[image]

please help me to solve this.

Comment: is CORS enabled ? please read more about cors there should be small setting should fix it.

Comment: Read the message carefully. The server is not accepting the request with header field`authorization`

Comment: yeah CORS enabled in browser and php backend.

Comment: Its getting same error after hosting also.

Answer (score 0):

**CHOICE 1**

Create a `proxy.conf.json` file in your angular and add following code

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",  //Your Targeted server host 
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Go to `angular.json` and add following code under **serve** command

```
 "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
```

Code looks like

```
   "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "sample:build",
              "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          }
```

**CHOICE 2**

Simply go to chrome store and download the extenstion called **Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *** , turn it ON. Magic Happens.